# Laravel- Why "personal_access_tokens" table is created even after removing the migration file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-sanctum, laravel-migrations

I created a new project using Laravel version 10, generating several migration files. Subsequently, I removed certain pre-existing files that were present upon project creation from the migration directory, namely: `users`, `password_reset_tokens`, `failed_jobs`, and `personal_access_tokens`.

However, upon attempting to execute the migrate command to establish the schema within the database, I observed that `personal_access_tokens` was also being created.

Despite efforts to clear the cache, dump the database, and retry, the issue persisted.

I explored two potential solutions:

1. Insert `Sanctum::ignoreMigrations()` within the register method of the `AppServiceProvider.php` class.
2. Uninstall/Remove the Sanctum package, which was pre-installed upon creating the Laravel application, and remove the `sanctum.php` configuration file from the `config` folder.

My confusion lies in why the `personal_access_tokens` table is being generated despite deleting its corresponding migration file. How is it triggered to create a table, and how does it retrieve schema details even after the migration file is removed?

Furthermore, when attempting to remove the Sanctum dependency from the `composer.json` file, I also had to delete the `sanctum.php` file from the config folder. Shouldn't there be a mechanism that automatically removes all dependencies of a package when it is uninstalled?

Comment: Composer doesn't know if you "published" anything from a package you installed. It won't remove any published files. In addition what probably happens is that the package always runs the migration and publishing it only allows you to customize it. Keep in mind that the `personal_access_tokens` migration is not one that comes by default with Laravel but rather is one that comes with sanctum. I'm not sure why you also got sanctum with a base Laravel install, that should not have happened unless you followed the wrong installation guide

Comment: @apokryfos Sanctum comes pre-installed since Laravel 9 including all auth related tables, you'd need to uninstall it if you wont use it

Comment: isnt Sanctum installed when you run starter kit?

Comment: @apokryfos What if I install some random package and it creates many references so Is there any way to remove the references also when we want to uninstall some dependency. Because, it would be hectic to check the references and delete those files or imports which aren't necessary after removing a package.

Also, sanctum was pre-installed when I created the application for the first time and I followed the Laravel official documentation itself. Thanks silver for clarifying

Comment: @silver I did not realise that. That actually sucks.

Comment: @AnshBargoti normally installing Laravel packages does not add anything in your own source code until you run a `publish` command for that package. It seems that the boilerplate Laravel code comes with this publishing pre-done and with sanctum preinstalled. I would personally just give up and just let the additional table be (even if it will be empty) it looks like more trouble than it's worth to remove it. Your code will run ok with sanctum there as long as you never make any use of it

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for clarifying the role of `publish` command. I tried to install `sanctum` package & check the flow and got to know that `vendor/laravel/sanctum` folder does contain a migration of `personal_access_tokens` table and when we publish the sanctum configuration then only the migration file & config file will be copied to application folder.

Comment: Continuing the last reply as it was long...
@apokryfos
Please correct me if I'm wrong. So, basically Laravel's migration system scans both the application's database/migrations directory and any package directories for migration files, and this allows it to find and execute migrations from packages we've installed even we haven't explicitly published the Sanctum package to our application.

Comment: @AnshBargoti each package written for Laravel  can "augment" laravel with additional configuration (including migrations). This is achieved by providing the location of the service provider in the packages [`composer.json`](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/3.x/composer.json#L48) (in this case it's `SanctumServiceProvider`). Sanctum will register its migrations (among other things) when the service provider runs [the code is here](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/3.x/src/SanctumServiceProvider.php#L68).